# Async LINQ queries null when using Entity Framework 6 with Azure SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, async-await, azure-sql-database

I have a web application that I recently moved to Azure. In it I have quite a few queries that use EF's async LINQ extensions (examples below). Since migrating to Azure, however, I have noticed that not only are some of these queries returning `null`, but MiniProfiler isn't even registering them:

```
// returns null. No queries logged in MiniProfiler
var someUser = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)

// works 100% as expected
var someUser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)
```

I've also tried "tricking" it by calling `.ToListAsync().FirstOrDefault()`. Of course, this didn't work either.

For what it's worth, this app uses .NET 4.5 and EF6. It has also been running in a traditionally-hosted production environment for ~18 months.

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but I've been having a tough time finding any information on it.

---

**EDIT:** The `id` in the example above is actually coming from a separate method that gets the current user id from the current principal:

```
// .GetUserId() is an extension method to get the userid from the principal
// Works with SQL Server
// Does not work with Azure SQL
var someUser = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == HttpContext.Current.GetUserId());
```

To fix this, I pulled that call out:

```
var userId = HttpContext.Current.GetUserId();
var someUser = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
```

Still, though, does anyone know *why* this works with traditional SQL Server, but not when connecting to an Azure SQL database?

Comment: For the first method, is the entire call stack using Async?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yes, the entire call stack is async in this case. It's coming from an async MVC action

Comment: @valverij - are there any `Task<T>.Result` calls anywhere in that method or in calls made to other methods in that request? Have you tried making the method as simple as possible, nothing but that `return await context.Users.ToListAsync();` in the main body of the mvc Action?

Comment: @Igor Wow, I feel dumb now. So, the id there is *actually* coming from the HttpContext, which is returning *null* for when called from within the async query. I've noticed this happening occasionally (I realize why it happens), and have been pulling these out periodically. This wasn't happening previously, when using SQL Server. Do you know why it is with Azure SQL? Is it just a difference in the underlying EF SQL provider?

Comment: @valverij - not sure but apparently the http context is not carried over to the async call being executed by Sql Azure, maybe because it also uses http to connect?

Comment: @valverij Do you make queries under TransactionScope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing async code EF6 uses `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent deadlocks, so the continuation (the method body after the await) is no longer guaranteed to execute the same thread.

When running on a local SQL Server the time the thread is blocked is usually below some threshold and therefore the continuation is executed synchronously to avoid context switching. However SQL Azure has more latency and triggers proper asynchronous execution resulting in the context being lost in this case.

ASP.NET only sets `HttpContext.Current` on the request thread, so when EF evaluates the lambda on the thread pool thread it will be null.

Comment: in other words, store that Id in a local variable before passing it into EF LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the "ToListAsync" at the end of the query? I believe the malfunction may be there because of the [LINQ deferred execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/)

Comment: Look at the question, yes I tried that. Also, FirstOrDefault, much like ToList, forces execution, so deferred execution is not an issue here